# Suport Vector Machines optimization – why multiply by 1/2?

Tags: svm, optimization

In the primal version of the SVM problem, the term $\|w\|^2$ is divided by 2 for mathematical convenience. I fail to see this so called mathematical convenience caused by this change. If one were to ignore this division by 2, the resultant dual form of the problem would have a coefficient with a value of 1/4 somewhere. By dividing by 2 in that earlier step, one instead has a coefficient of 1/2 in that same position. I fail to understand why this slight change from 1/4 to 1/2 is considered a major source of mathematical convenience.

Comment: Not sure, but it could be similar to why they divide the cost function in linear regression by 2. It's just added there because it doesn't hamper with the optimisation and conveniently cancels the 2 which appears due to the derivative of the $∥w∥2$ term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to make the Langrange multiplier formulation a little less messy, specifically for the partial derivative to $\mathbf{w}$ as was hinted in the comment:
$$
\begin{align}
L_p &= \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{w}||^2+C\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i
-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\Big[y_i\big(\langle\mathbf{w},\varphi(\mathbf{x}_i)\rangle+b\big)-(1-\xi_i)\Big]-\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i\xi_i, \\
\frac{\partial L_p}{\partial \mathbf{w}}&=\mathbf{w}-\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i y_i \varphi(\mathbf{x}_i),
\end{align}
$$
where $\xi$ is the vector of slack variables, $\alpha$ the vector of support weights, $b$ the bias and $\varphi(\cdot)$ the embedding function.

A direct result of this convention and the KKT conditions (which imply $\frac{\partial L_p}{\partial \mathbf{w}}=0$) is the well-known form of the separating hyperplane $\mathbf{w}$ *in the feature space spanned by $\varphi(\cdot)$*:
$$
\mathbf{w}=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i y_i \varphi(\mathbf{x}_i),
$$
and the decision function $f(\cdot)$:
$$
f(\mathbf{z}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i y_i \kappa(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{z}) + b = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i y_i \langle \varphi(\mathbf{x}_i), \varphi(\mathbf{z})\rangle + b,
$$
with $\kappa(\cdot,\cdot)$ the kernel function.